# Data Manipulation with Python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, time

I am facing a problem with manipulation this table:

```
date            time         V_1    I_1      V_2    I_2     Temp
07.07.2017  12:36:27.801    0.000   0.532   0.001   1.289   25.655
07.07.2017  12:36:27.802    0.000   0.486   0.001   1.273   25.655
07.07.2017  12:36:27.803    0.000   0.482   0.001   1.322   25.655
07.07.2017  12:36:27.804    0.000   0.435   0.001   1.311   25.655
```

I need the time differences (802-801 = 1ms) between each row but I cannot find any solution to handling this without a loop.
Is there a more pythonic way?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) with [`diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.diff.html) and then get [`total_seconds`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.total_seconds.html) and multiple by `1000` for `ms`:

```
df['diff'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'] + ' ' + df['time']).diff().dt.total_seconds() * 1000
print (df)
         date          time  V_1    I_1    V_2    I_2    Temp  diff
0  07.07.2017  12:36:27.801  0.0  0.532  0.001  1.289  25.655   NaN
1  07.07.2017  12:36:27.802  0.0  0.486  0.001  1.273  25.655   1.0
2  07.07.2017  12:36:27.803  0.0  0.482  0.001  1.322  25.655   1.0
3  07.07.2017  12:36:27.804  0.0  0.435  0.001  1.311  25.655   1.0
```

For comparing first value with column use [`sub`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.sub.html) with [`iat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.iat.html) for select first value of column:

```
df['diff'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'] + ' ' + df['time'])
df['diff'] =  df['diff'].sub(df['diff'].iat[0]).dt.total_seconds() * 1000
print (df)
         date          time  V_1    I_1    V_2    I_2    Temp  diff
0  07.07.2017  12:36:27.801  0.0  0.532  0.001  1.289  25.655   0.0
1  07.07.2017  12:36:27.802  0.0  0.486  0.001  1.273  25.655   1.0
2  07.07.2017  12:36:27.803  0.0  0.482  0.001  1.322  25.655   2.0
3  07.07.2017  12:36:27.804  0.0  0.435  0.001  1.311  25.655   3.0
```

Comment: Thank you, it works.
Unfortunately it is very very slowly. Takes 150 seconds for 117540 rows.
Any suggestions to speed it up?

Comment: oh, and what I forgot: how can I calculate the time difference to the first row to tu current row? diff() seems not to have a working arg for that

Comment: `diff` is very fast, I try some numpy solutions, but all was slowier. I add soluton for difference first value with column.